# ASP.net MVC3 & Spring.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, spring, spring.net

What is practical difference between ASP.net MVC3 & Spring.Net. What would you suggest to use for a new application. Does Spring.net is actively developed and supported?

And whether both are compatible with each other and can be used together?

Any idea would be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring.NET is a Dependency Injection framework for .NET.

ASP.NET is a framework for developing web applications on top of ASP.NET using the MVC pattern.

So it's like asking `What is practical difference between an apple and an orange`.

Comment: And in terms of DI containers Spring would be very low on my list of ones to use.  Ninject, StructureMap, Windsor are all much more widely used in the .Net community.

Comment: @ShaneCourtrille, actually I have used Spring.NET for many years in lots of my past projects since I had some Java background back in the time. But I agree that today I would probably go with Ninject although that's a bit subjective.

Comment: From the discussions I've seen and been involved with you are in a very small minority.